# In gdb -2147483648=2147483648

Tags: gcc, gdb

In gdb,

```
(gdb) p -2147483648
$28 = 2147483648
(gdb) pt -2147483648
type = unsigned int
```

Since `-2147483648` is within the range of type `int`, why is gdb treating it as an `unsigned int`?

```
(gdb) pt -2147483647-1
type = int
(gdb) p -2147483647-1
$27 = -2147483648
```

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your own question here.

Comment: The `type = unsigned int` right after a negative number hints at `pt` not being all that reliable when used in this way.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking. Please review it to make sure I haven't changed the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb` appears to be following a set of rules for determining the type of a decimal integer literal that are inconsistent with the rules given by the C standard.

I'll assume your system has a 32-bit `int` and `long int` types, using 2's-complement and no padding bits (that's a common choice for 32-bit systems, and it's consistent with what you're seeing). Then the ranges of `int` and `unsigned int` are:

- `int`: `-2147483648` .. `+2147483647`
- `unsigned int`: `0` .. `4294967295`

and the ranges of `long int` and `unsigned long int` are the same.

`2147483647` is within the range of type `int`, so that's its type.

Since the value of `2147483648` is outside the range of type `int`, apparently `gdb` is choosing to treat it as an `unsigned int`. And `-2147483648` is not an integer literal, it's an *expression* consisting of a unary `-` operator applied to the constant `2147483648`. Since `gdb` treats `2147483648` as an `unsigned int`, it also treats `-2147483648` as an `unsigned int`, and the unary `-` operator for unsigned types wraps around, yielding `2147483648`.

As for `-2147483647-1`, that's an expression all of whose operands are of type `int`, and there's no overflow.

In all versions of ISO C, though, an unsuffixed decimal literal can never be of type `unsigned int`. In C90, its type is the first of:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`

that can represent its value. Under C99 rules (and later), the type of a decimal integer constant is the first of:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

that can represent its value.

I don't know whether there's a way to tell `gdb` to use C rules for integer literals.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that gdb applies the unary negation operator after setting the type of the digit value:

In case 1: gdb parses `2147483648` which overflows `int` type and becomes `unsigned int`. Then it applies the negation.

In case 2: `2147483647` is a valid `int` and stays int when negation and subtraction are subsequently applied.